# Re-formatting txt file in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, awk, scripting

I have a file contains the name of a process, the number of times it died, and the reason it died. The file looks like this:

```
  26 posix.cc:529 ---PROCESS: cat

  18 XtWindowOfObject () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6 ---PROCESS: dog

  16 _XtAddCallbackOnce () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6 ---PROCESS: dog

  16 Matrix.cc:4399 ---PROCESS: cat

  9 vtable for CollapsibleEvent () from /srg/release/lib.so ---PROCESS: bird

  1 raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6 ---PROCESS: dog

  1 raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6 ---PROCESS: cat

  1 ?? () ---PROCESS: cat
```

I want to use a command which rearranges it so it has the following 3 columns like so:

```
  CAT PROCESS CORES:
  cat     26     posix.cc:529
  cat     16     Matrix.cc:4399
  cat     1      raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
  cat     1      ?? ()

  DOG PROCESS CORES:
  dog     18     XtWindowOfObject () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6
  dog     16     _XtAddCallback () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6
  dog     1      raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6

 BIRD PROCESS CORES: 
  bird    9     vtable for CollapsibleEvent () from /srg/release/lib.so
```

The process names are always changing as the file is produced daily. Please help - I've been trying to use awk but I just can't work out how to set the delimiters correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use perl:

```
perl -lanE 'if(/\w/){push @{$r{@F[-1]}},[$F[0],"@F[1..$#F-2]"]}}{for$k(sort keys%r){say uc($k)." PROCESS CORES:";say join"\t",$k,@{$_}for@{$r{$k}}}' < input_file.txt
```

or readable

```
perl -lanE '
if( /\w/ ) { #if the line contains any word character
        push @{$r{@F[-1]}}, [ $F[0], "@F[1 .. $#F-2]" ] #store by last word
}
}{ #eskimo
for $k (sort keys %r) { #for each type
        say uc($k)." PROCESS CORES:";
        say join "\t", $k, @{$_} for @{$r{$k}} #print lines
}
' < input_file.txt
```

produces:

```
BIRD PROCESS CORES:
bird    9       vtable for CollapsibleEvent () from /srg/release/lib.so
CAT PROCESS CORES:
cat     26      posix.cc:529
cat     16      Matrix.cc:4399
cat     1       raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
cat     1       ?? ()
DOG PROCESS CORES:
dog     18      XtWindowOfObject () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6
dog     16      _XtAddCallbackOnce () from /usr/lib64/libXt.so.6
dog     1       raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk command:

```
awk '
/./{ process = $NF
     split($0,info,/---PROCESS:/)
     accumulate[process] = accumulate[process] process " " info[1] "\n"
}
END {
  n = asorti(accumulate, sorted)
  for(i = 1;i<=n;i++){
    process = sorted[i]
    caps = toupper(process)
    printf "\n%s PROCESS CORES:\n%s\n",caps, accumulate[process]
  }
}'
```